# Принудительный вызов метода super() при его перегрузке наследником

Tags: kotlin

Можно ли как-то принудить вызов метода `super()` при его перегрузке наследником?

Answer (score 1):

используй аннотацию `@CallSuper` для super метода

Comment: К сожалению эта аннотация для Android